# Magento Shipping Method problems

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

My problem is that i made ZIP Code optional, but now, if i write any number in the box, shipping methods are dissapearing .
i can write everything in the One Page Checkout, but when i get to zip code (which is optional now), and i write something, shipping methods dissaper and i try to finish order, i get

> Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping
>   methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your
>   shipping address.

If anyone knows how to solve this, thank you

Comment: One would assume if magento doesn't know where to ship it to that it won't be able to come up with a shipping estimate. You might try http://magento.stackexchange.com though, they probably know better.

Comment: UPS, FedEx and USPS all depend on having a Zip/Postal code to work with, or was it other ship methods that weren't coming up?

Comment: Its not UPS FEDEX OR USPS, i`m from Romania, we normaly need a zipcode, but i dont want to be a required field. So i modified it somewhere ( Dont remember where ) and made it optional. But now, when i enter a zip code, my two shipping methods are dissapearing. if i delete zip code, they appear again.